# Issue with javax.mail and attached file

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to send an email with javax.mail.

It works on ubuntu 14.04 and java 1.8.0_121 and tomcat7

With ubuntu 18.04 and java 1.8.0_181 and tomcat8 I am getting this error :

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: "text/html" DataContentHandler
>   requires String object, was given object of type class
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

Here is the code :

```
MimeMessage mex = new MimeMessage(session);
mex.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
mex.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress((String)((List)ccList).get(0)));
mex.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, from);
mex.setSubject(subject);

MimeMultipart var26 = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachBodyPart.setText(messageBody);
var26.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
new FileDataSource(fileName);
attachBodyPart.setDisposition("attachment");
attachBodyPart.setContent(data, "application/pdf");
attachBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
var26.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
mex.setContent(var26, "text/html");
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(param.getSmtpHost(), from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(mex, mex.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to believe this same code works anywhere.

Change

```
attachBodyPart.setText(messageBody);
```

to

```
attachBodyPart.setText(messageBody, "html");
```

Change

```
mex.setContent(var26, "text/html");
```

to

```
mex.setContent(var26);
```

Comment: Same error with this correction. Do you know the meaning of  this IOException ?

Comment: I would think of something with folder rights, or something like that while the attached file is built?

Comment: If you're getting the same error then you did something wrong.  Perhaps you didn't update the code properly, or perhaps the updated code is not the code that's running.  Also, make sure you're using the official JavaMail release, not the GNU version of JavaMail that is sometimes included with Linux systems.  If none of that helps, post your updated code and the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: your suggestion did finally work. It appears that jaxax.mail setContent method has changed between the two versions of java.

Comment: It has not changed.